Почему вместо соединительной гласной ставят дефис
юго-восток
финско-русский

ясно же, что тут обычная соединительная гласная, не?
юговосток
финскорусский

Вот даже и словарь путается в показаниях:

Краснобурый

То же, что красно-бурый



Это философский вопрос, и решение должно быть соответствующее. Если соединительная гласная только соединяет,  то дефис может соединять или разделять. Соединять второй раз не имеет смысла, поэтому дефис, вероятно, отменяет соединение.  Это в качестве исходной версии для решения задачи.   А дальше, я думаю, вам несложно будет продолжить)

@Sharon философский вопрос это "Какова цель жизни?", а здесь вопрос орфографии

В орфографии есть своя философия и у девиза тоже. @Sharon Зачем же нам сначала соединять с помощью гласной, а затем разъединять с помощью девиза?

Вот это самый интересный момент.  Мы хотим, чтобы выбранная  форма письма выражала не соединение или разделение, а нечто среднее. На этом я, пожалуй, остановлюсь, мне любопытно будет послушать другие ответы. Мне эта тема и раньше была интересна. А теперь после разговоров о дефисе добавилось новое понимание знака, надо будет еще подумать.  // А почему вы пишете "девиз"?

@user190920 ДВА результата поисковика по «философии орфографии». Оба абы какие. Ни учебников, ни научных статей. Вопрос на том и закрыт. А будь таковая реально поддисцпиплиной орфографии, это всё равно был бы вопрос орфографии (как засолка — вопрос кулинарии). Шарон дословно поумничала, дескать это вопрос философский. Не додумывайте того, чего не писали.

Результатов миллион, это фактически языковая норма, если иметь в виду общую конструкцию: философия программирования, философия брака, философия бизнеса, философия спорта


Юго-восток

Вот что говорил о дефисном написании этого и подобного ему слов один из разработчиков «ПРАВИЛ РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ И ПУНКТУАЦИИ» 1956 года А.Б. Шапиро:

§ 91. Полуслитно (через дефис) пишутся:
…Сложные названия промежуточных стран света, например: юго-запад, северо-запад, норд-ост, зюйд-вест. В написаниях существительных данного типа наблюдаются колебания: их пишут нередко слитно («югозапад», «нордост» и т. п.). Однако полуслитное написание целесообразнее, так как оно способствует более отчетливому восприятию двойственного характера этих слов, обе составные части которых одинаково существенны для значения всего слова в целом.
(Шапиро А.Б. «Русское правописание». М., 1951)


Думаю, такой же логикой руководствовались разработчики «Правил…» и при выборе дефисного написания для сложных прилагательных типа финско-русский, обозначающих двусторонние отношения.

Да, похоже ничего лучшего, чем "более отчетливое восприятие" за этим не стоит.

Похоже, что откровения господина  Шапиро – это вершина философской лингвистической мысли. Правда, в правилах !956 года и в современных справочниках почему-то это изречение не упоминается.  И если все дело  отчетливости, то следует все сложные слова писать через дефис – и никаких проблем! В то же время решения по различным темам принимаются, и хотелось бы знать, кто же и как всем этим управляет? Или не хотелось бы?

Sharon: «Похоже, что откровения господина Шапиро – это вершина философской лингвистической мысли. Правда, в правилах !956 года…» === Sharon, наверное, Вас опять подводит невнимательность к написанному другими: Шапиро А.Б.  как раз и являлся одним из основных разработчиков правил 1956 года!

Да ладно вам, я будто не знаю Абрама Борисовича. Тот еще шутник был, слова категории состояния назвал беспризорными. Там было 10 академиков, Шапиро как раз младшенький среди них.  Кто-то руководил, а кто-то помогал, кто-то потом присоединился) Разве теперь разберешь.  //Так с кого мне теперь спрашивать, почему одни слова пишутся отчетливо, а другие нет. Может, в вашем философском кружке кто знает.

Предлагается вашему вниманию книга  https://docviewer.yandex.ru/view/13281456/?page=1&*=3Wz3VhtkTTiPXAQg1B46GUH%2FX%2FZ7InVybCI6InlhLWRpc2s6Ly8vZGlzay%2FQl9Cw0LPRgNGD0LfQutC4LzdiOTY5Y2Q0LTk3MWUtMTFlZC05ODk0LTAwNTA1NmI5Mzk2MSIsInRpdGxlIjoiN2I5NjljZDQtOTcxZS0xMWVkLTk4OTQtMDA1MDU2YjkzOTYxIiwibm9pZnJhbWUiOmZhbHNlLCJ1aWQiOiIxMzI4MTQ1NiIsInRzIjoxNzMxNjA3MzMxNDQ1LCJ5dSI6Ijk3MzkzNzMzMDE3MTk4NTE1NTgifQ%3D%3D
Чжао Пэнсян
СТАНОВЛЕНИЕ НОРМ ПОЛУСЛИТНЫХ (ДЕФИСНЫХ)
НАПИСАНИЙ В РУССКОЙ ОРФОГРАФИИ XIX‒XX ВВ.
 Диссертация на соискание ученой степени
 кандидата филологических наук

В частности там рассматривается орфография названий частей света и говорится о колебаниях в письме: дефис — слитно — дефис — слитно — дефис. Правда колебания незначительные, дефисное написание все же преобладало.
Примечание. Интересно, что части света одно время писались с прописной буквы: Юго-Западъ или Юго-западъ.
Почему же менялось написание? Из-за соединительной гласной: время от времени это фактор раздражал лингвистическое сознание, и тогда переходили к слитному письму. Противоположная сторона настаивала на дефисном по образцу норд-ост.
Но вот в 1933 году кодифицируется слитное письмо, и кто же авторы? Не поверите — А. Б. Шапиро и М. И. Уаров, Справочник по русскому языку.  А как же "отчетливое восприятие двойственного характера слов"? Какая непоследовательность! Но в 1956 году опять вернулись к дефису.
Что меня удивляет в этой истории, так это отсутствие хоть сколько-нибудь понятного объяснения дефиса при наличии соединительной гласной. Это все же наука, и как-то несерьезно ссылаться на отчетливость и на двойственность. В русском языке много сложных прилагательных со слитным написанием, в том числе парных вариантов, и все они с двухсторонними отношениями — все же две основы)
В этой теме дается объяснение дефисного написания в качестве версии:
Почему страны света пишутся через дефис: юго-запад, северо-восток? Дефис и соединительная гласная одновременно?

ссылка не открывается
